# How to concatenate operator into where Clause ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working with the stored procedure in SQL server 2008 I have written the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_]      
@jobNumber VARCHAR(60),
@customerId VARCHAR(6),
@isType BIT

AS  

BEGIN  
DECLARE 
    @dynamicDir BIT,
    @permit VARCHAR(6),
    @fPSVersion VARCHAR(2)
SELECT @dynamicDir = [EDEXMIS].[dbo].[CM].[DynamicDirs] FROM [EDEXMIS].[dbo].[CM]
        WHERE [EDEXMIS].[dbo].[CM].[CustID] = @customerId 
IF @isType = 1 
    BEGIN 
        IF @dynamicDir = 0 
            BEGIN
                SET @permit = 'FAX'
                SET @fPSVersion = '='
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @permit = 'FAX'
                SET @fPSVersion = '>'
            END
    END
Select * From MM where Permit =@permit and FPSVersion "Here i want the variable value @fpsVersion" 1                    

END
```

But i don't know how to con-cat the conditional operator in the where clause .I think i am doing it wrongly but If there is any other way to do it please suggest . Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_]

    @customerId VARCHAR(6),
    @isType BIT

AS BEGIN 

    DECLARE 
        @permit VARCHAR(6),
        @fPSVersion VARCHAR(2)

    SELECT 
          @fPSVersion = CASE WHEN t.DynamicDirs = 0 THEN '=' ELSE '>' END
        , @permit = 'FAX'
    FROM dbo.CM t
    WHERE t.CustID = @customerId 
        AND @isType = 1

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.MM 
    WHERE Permit = ''' + @permit + '''
        AND FPSVersion ''' + @fPSVersion + ''' 1'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Comment: This is better than the first because future values of @fPSVersion are taken care of.

Comment: Can i create the complete separate sp for my second select query as it is also complicated and then call that sp from this sp and return the dataset from this sp

Comment: @Curiosity, I'm not sure that understood you correctly. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @Devart I want to know that can i create the new stored procedure     for the SELECT SQL and then call that procedure from this procedure      and return the selected values. Is it possible

Comment: @Curiosity - yes, of course. Try to use `INSERT INTO EXEC` construction.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
SELECT *
FROM MM
WHERE
    Permit = @permit 
    AND (FPSVersion = 1 AND @dynamicDir = 0)
    OR (FPSVersion > 1 AND @dynamicDir <> 0)
```

Comment: If the logic changes to include < or other operators then this would need further mods. Below answer by Devart does not break the D.R.Y rule

Comment: true, but DevArt's rule also invokes dynamic SQL, which can lead to performance issues (if used improperly).